# python input() and print() in multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am using win10 and python 3.7.3 32-bit

I am trying to achieve the following: every second a data read-out is performed an printed, while a control loop waits for user input to control a device. see my code:

```
import device
import threading
from threading import Lock

def print_data(t_start):
    while True:
        data=getData() # generic example
        print(f'data: {data} at time {time.time()-t_start}')

def control_func():
    while True:
        in_ = input(' Press ENTER to switch ON, Press x to quit')
        if in_ == '':
            device.on()
            print('device ON')
        elif in_ == 'x' or in_ == 'X':
            device.off()
            sys.exit()
        else: continue

        in_ = input(' Press ENTER to switch OFF, Press x to quit')
        if in_ == '':
            device.off()
            print('device OFF')
        elif in_ == 'x' or in_ == 'X':
            device.off()
            sys.exit()
        else: continue

t_start = time.time()
device=device()

trd1 = threading.Thread(target=control_func())
trd2 = threading.Thread(target=print_data(t_start))


trd1.start() # starting the thread 1 
trd2.start() # starting the thread 2

trd1.join()
trd2.join()
```

This only gives me the input statements from  `control_func()` or the prints from  `print_data()`

Same wih using mutliprocessing.
I didn't manage to make the two functions run simultanously.
replacing  `print()` with

```
s_print_lock = Lock()
# Define a function to call print with the Lock

def s_print(*a, **b):
    """Thread safe print function"""
    with s_print_lock:
        print(*a, **b)
```

also didn't do the trick.
Since I am noob, please help. Or should I do a different approach all together?

Comment: it might has to do with the fact that the print of the subprocesses are buffered. try to do a `sys.stdout.flush()` after the print.

Comment: @user_na: Easier: Add `flush=True` as an argument to each `print` call; it's been supported since 3.3 (give or take).

Answer (score 1):

You *called* the functions in the process of creating the `Thread`, you didn't *pass* the functions to the `Thread` for it to execute, so no actual work occurred in the threads. Change the `Thread` creation to:

```
trd1 = threading.Thread(target=control_func)  # Remove call parens
trd2 = threading.Thread(target=print_data, args=(t_start,))  # Remove call parens and pass args tuple separately
```

so the functions themselves are passed, and the `Thread` actually runs them in the separate logical thread of execution. As written, you ran `control_func` to completion, then ran `print_data` to completion, then launched two `Thread`s with `target=None` (the returned value from both functions) which do nothing, then `join`ed the `Thread`s doing nothing.

Additional notes:

1. If you're using `multiprocessing`, make sure to use `multiprocessing.Lock`, not `threading.Lock` (the latter is only guaranteed to work within a single process)
2. While the threaded cases likely doesn't require a lock (at least on CPython where the GIL protects against issues) if you're only printing a single atomic thing at a time, for `multiprocessing` you should definitely use the lock and add `flush=True` to all `print`s; without the `flush=True`, the actual output might be delayed indefinitely.
3. You need to provide some means to communicate that the loop is done to `print_data`; as written, `control_func` will `sys.exit()`, but that only exits *that thread*, not the program. Unless `getData` will somehow throw an exception as a result of `control_func` exiting, `print_data` will never exit, and therefore neither will the main thread.

Solutions for #3 include:

1. Using a `threading.Event()`; make a global `should_stop = threading.Event()`, change the `print_data` loop to `while not should_stop.is_set():`, and after `trd1.join()` returns, have the main thread call `should_stop.set()`
2. Make `trd2` a `daemon` thread, and don't bother to `join` it (assumes it can die immediately when `trd1` and the main thread have ended; might not hold for your scenario); it will die forcefully when all non-`daemon` threads have exited.

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed it.
solutions for #3 second option was very easy to implement